# Can I use different User1... User9 colors for active and inactive panes?

Tags: vim-windows, colorscheme, statusline

I know `User1`... `User9` colors the status line. I have applied several colors to the statusline to make it easy to recognize, but I wish this is only applied to active panes, not inactive panes. So that inactive panes has monocolor statusline, and is not too distracting. I suppose this is possible if there are two sets of `User1`... `User9`, one for active panes, one for inactive panes. Is there such function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the issue you should just use User1-5 for the active and the 6-9 for the inactive one.

For example I use the following in my update function (not complete but you should get the idea):

```
" active
let s:a_statusline='%1* %<%f ' " ... etc.
" inactive
let s:na_statusline='%6* %<%f ' " ... etc.

function! s:RefreshStatus()
  for i in range(1, winnr('$'))
    call setwinvar(i, '&statusline', '%!LaktakGetStatus(' . i . ')')
  endfor
endfunction

function! LaktakGetStatus(w)
  return a:w==winnr() ? s:a_statusline : s:na_statusline
endfunction

autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * call <SID>RefreshStatus()
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I made a few modifications to rid syntax errors, which I will explain below (sorry I haven't had time to check this for last few days.)

Answer (score 0):

I will post my code as an answer to make it more visible. (Disclaimer: @laktak has included a `<SID>` number, but it causes errors, and I have not understood its purpose.)

```
" To set the statusline for all windowss.
function! RefreshStatusLine()
    for i in range(1, winnr('$'))
        call setwinvar(i, '&statusline', '%!GetStatusLine(' . i . ')')
    endfor
endfunction

" To choose the statusline for either active or inactive windowss.
function! GetStatusLine(num_active_window)
    return a:num_active_window==winnr() ? s:active_statusline : s:inactive_statusline
endfunction

" First to define that for the only active windows.
let s:active_statusline='%1* %F %*%2*%m%r%h%*%3* B:%n %*%4* L:%l/%L %*%5* C:%c%V %*'
" Next to define those for other inactive windowss.
let s:inactive_statusline=' %F %m%r%h B:%n  L:%l/%L  C:%c%V '

" Set the statusline whenever the active windows changes.
autocmd VimEnter,WinEnter,BufWinEnter * call RefreshStatusLine()

" The following lines must come after colorscheme declaration
highlight User1 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#660000
highlight User2 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#990033
highlight User3 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#666600
highlight User4 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#336633
highlight User5 guifg=#ffffff  guibg=#336699
```

Comment: <SID> is used with functions that are local to the script - see `s:RefreshStatus()` and `help <SID>`